# Not able to fetch records from DB through python by using Parameterized Queries

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, pyodbc

The above function has parameters endTime, startTime, list1 and column_filter to it and I am trying to read a query by making the WHERE clause conditions parameterized.

```
endT = endTime 
startT = startTime
myList = ",".join("'" + str(i) + "'" for i in list1)
queryArgs = {'db': devDB,
             'schema': dbo,
             'table': table_xyz,
             'columns': ','.join(column_filter)}

 query = '''
         WITH TIME_SERIES AS
         (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LocId ORDER BY Created_Time DESC) RANK, {columns} 
         from {schema}.{table}
         WHERE s_no in  ? AND
         StartTime >= ? AND
         EndTime <=  ?  )
         SELECT {columns} FROM TIME_SERIES WHERE RANK = 1 
         '''.format(**queryArgs)

 args = (myList, startT, endT)
 return self.read(query, args)
```

The below is my read which connects to the DB to fetch records and a condition is also added to check if its parameterized or not.

```
    def read(self, query, parameterValues = None):
        cursor = self.connect(cursor=True)
        if parameterValues is not None:
            rows = cursor.execute(query, parameterValues)
        else:
            rows = cursor.execute(query)

        df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows.fetchall())
        if len(df.columns) > 0:
            df.columns = [x[0] for x in cursor.description]
        cursor.close()
        return df
```

The query args are getting picked up but not the parameterized values. In my case, it is going inside the read method with parameter values of (myList, startT ,endT) as a tuple. The query in WHERE clause remains unchanged (parameters not able to replace ? ), and as a result I am not able to fetch any records. Can you specify where I might be going wrong?

Comment: Your query text in 1st codeblock is wrong. You use CTE and ROW_NUMBER() - so MySQL version is 8. But in this version the word `RANK` is reserved. You use it as column alias without proper quoting - according error message will be generated. I'd recommend to alter it (for example, to `row_rank` or `rownumber`)..

Comment: i dont think that's an issue. I am not facing errors. Just the fact that when query is built, the args arent getting picked up by the query.